# Dependency Injection in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

Is Dependency Injection optional?

I'm a newbie to ASP.NET MVC3 and finding it hard to grasp the implementation of this particualr concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's completely optional, so don't let that stop you from learning the basics.

Comment: aka Dependency Injection By Hand